# How to change my functions behavior to not use a Model class in C# API

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

First, I am not sure if my question reflects my needs, please let me know if that needs to be changed.

What I am doing here is creating functions in DLL application to be called from DotNET outside C#. The issue with my function now is the Model class. Where I am going to use this DLL, I cannot see/use my model class from the outside, therefore how do I change my code to use a string instead of Product model? I still need to send my request as JSON though.

1. I am working with JSON
2. I have the following 2 classes:

In Class 1 (`SetupWebAPIAsync`): Function that puts a product (Model)

```
public static async Task<ApiResponse> PutProductAsync(string endpoint, Product p)
    {

        StringContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        string result = "";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(endpoint, httpContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return new ApiResponse(response.StatusCode, result);
    }
```

In Class 2:

```
 public static ApiResponse PutIn(string user, string password, string endpoint , Product Httpcontent)
    {
        User = user;
        Password = password;
        Endpoint = endpoint;
        Content = Httpcontent;
        ExecutePUTRequest().Wait();
        return apiResponse;
    }
    private static async Task ExecutePUTRequest()
    {
        SetupWebAPIAsync.SetAPIAuthentication(User, Password);
        apiResponse = await SetupWebAPIAsync.PutProductAsync(Endpoint,Content);
    }
```

My Model Class:

```
public class Product
  {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
    
}
ex:
{ 
     "id" : "12",
     "name" : "test",
    "inactive": false,

}
```

Now this is how I call my function and it works this way BUT I need to replace product by a string I pass in from my test outside Dll.

```
Product product = new Product { name = "API_Testing" };
PutIn("user", "pass", "https://localhost/api/product", product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't cause your `PutIn()` method expects an `Product Httpcontent` as method parameter. Instead take a stringified product as JSON and convert that to `product` and call the main method like

```cs
public static ApiResponse PutIn(string user, string password,
    string endpoint, string Httpcontent)
{
    User = user;
    Password = password;
    Endpoint = endpoint;
    Content = NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(Httpcontent);
    ExecutePUTRequest().Wait();
    return apiResponse;
}
```

You can then call it like

```cs
string product = "{id: 12, name: API_Testing, inactive: false,}"
PutIn("user", "pass", "https://localhost/api/product", product);
```

Comment: What I posted, works fine, I do not want to declare a Product product = new Product { name = "API_Testing" }; that's my issue :) , basically I want to change the behavior to not use a Model but still sends in a string JSON.

Comment: I am having issues parsing my string. I can just say string product = "{name : API_Testing}" right ?

Comment: @fazlook1 yes you can

Comment: getting this error +  $exception {"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path 'name', line 1, position 11."} Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException

Comment: Fixed it, it has to be like that  string product = "{\"name\" : \"API_Testing\"}";

Comment: Now I wonder if I have something like this: {
    "id": "04",
    "name": "API",
    "Settings": {
        "applyFilter": true,
         }

Comment: @fazlook1 you still can but your model schema has to change in order to deserialize